# Why will my jQuery Slider Angular Directive not update when I change the scope value

Tags: jquery, angularjs, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-slider

I have created a jQuery UI Slider Angular Directive. Here is my code:

**HTML**

```
<slider min="filters.price.min" max="filters.price.max" range="filters.price.range"></slider>
```

**Controller**

```
App.controller("MainController", function ($scope, $http) {
$scope.initFilters = function () {
    $scope.filters = {};
    $scope.filters.price = {};
    $scope.filters.price.min = 0;
    $scope.filters.price.max = 0;
    $scope.filters.price.range = [0, 0];
};
$scope.initFilters();

$http.get("someurl").success(function (data) {
    $scope.initFilters();
    $scope.filters.price = {};
    $scope.filters.price.min = 0;
    $scope.filters.price.max = 100;
    $scope.filters.price.range = [$scope.filters.price.min, $scope.filters.price.max];
    $scope.$broadcast("applyFilters");
});
});
```

**Directive**

```
    App.directive('slider', function () {
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: true,
    transclude: true,
    template: "<div class='slider'></div>",
    scope: {
        min: "=",
        max: "=",
        range: "="
    },
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        $(element).slider({
            range: (scope.range != undefined),
            min: scope.min,
            max: scope.max,
            values: [scope.min, scope.max],
            slide: function (event, ui) {
                scope.$apply(function () {
                    scope.range = ui.values;
                });
            }
        });
        scope.$on("applyFilters", function () {
            console.log("APPLY FILTERS:", scope);
            console.log("APPLY FILTERS:", scope.min, scope.max, scope.range);
        });
    }
}
});
```

As you can see from my code, my price slider is initialised to 0.

I then make a HTTP call to a webservice and upon receiving a response, I try setting the min, max and range values of the price slider to 0-100.

For some reason, my slider remains at 0 in the UI.

The console logs in the event handler are strangest though...

The first console log prints out the scope object, which has the correct values (i.e. min = 0, max = 100 and range = [0, 100]).

The second console log prints out the wrong values (i.e. min = 0, max = 0 and range = [0, 0]).

Please could someone help me understand why this is happening.

Thanks,

Ben Bullock

Comment: Place .then instead of .success.

Comment: Creating a fiddler/plunkr link would help the people here solve it fast.

Comment: I have created a plunkr which demonstrates the issue. See here:
https://plnkr.co/edit/E8sSh3Nh5F6SHLFszuWl?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

I think your applyFilters event handler is executed before directive's scope is updated. You can emit event with delay or force angular to update scope before firing event.

See this:
[plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/APmRL7CkJUZAIDXhXfDy?p=preview)

However this will not make your slider work as you expect. Slider was already created, so to modify its parametes you have to use `option` method, see
[docs](http://api.jqueryui.com/slider/#method-option).

I'd add watch on `min`, `max` and `range` like below:

```
scope.$watch("min", function(value) {
  slider.slider( "option", "min", value );
});      

scope.$watch("max", function(value) {
  slider.slider( "option", "max", value );
});      

scope.$watch("range", function(value) {
  slider.slider( "option", "range", value );
});
```

See complete code [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/LC3xew26gewJ1zLFJarL?p=info)